# SEO for CSS and JS hide/show

Tags: css, seo, show-hide

We're building a site for an academic institution. This institution offers many subjects, and we don't want to show all of them at once on the homepage. So we designed a homepage that shows the 2 main categories of studies, and clicking on a category will show a div with the list of subjects in that category.

Our client is worried SEO-wise about those div's being hidden on page-load. Is he correct in his concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read an article by Roger Johansson [on this subject](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201010/is_hiding_text_with_css_to_improve_accessibility_bad_for_seo/), and it seems that the conclusion is that as long as the **intent** isn't to show that content only to search engines, hiding is fine. I don't see any mention of preferring one method of hiding over the other.

In addition, in that post's comments there was a link to [an answer by a Google worker](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=50f9a4942ac605ec&hl=en) that said:

> Merely using display:none will not automatically trigger a penalty.  The key is whether or not there is a mechanism - either automatic or one that is invoked by the user - to make the content visible

In my case of course there will be such a mechanism, because we *want* our users to see that content, just not at page-load...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you hide them if you use a z-order or a far left off screen position they will still be read by the Google bot. if you use display none or hidden then it may have an effect on your SEO.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. Do you have a source upon which this data is based?

Comment: @LeaCohen not off the top of my head but a quick Google search for hiding content and SEO should bring up the answer. This method of hiding content also provides better accessibility.

Comment: I actually did search, and didn't find such a resource. I found what I wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8470773/278)

Answer (score 2):

You're right to have concern. Google will count some of or significantly reduce content that isn't displayed on page load. I would recommend letting the text display at load, then setting it to display none via JavaScript. This way the search engine picks it up.

You can do so with a simple jQuery [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) snippet like this:

```
<p class="remove">Text displayed on load.</p>

$j(document).ready(function(){
     $('.remove').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Ash. Do you think it's ok to call `$('.remove').hide();` on onready? Or is that too soon for Google?

Comment: @LeaCohen the race condition (will the Google bot see my links before I hide them) is why I recommended hiding them using a far left position this avoids the issue completely.

Comment: Great idea Lea, just wrapped the JavaScript with jQuery's ready. Steve mentioned left positioning such as text-indent: -9999px; and position: absolute;, but that's optional. Google will 'optionally' crawl JavaScript so there could be an advantage to using a JavaScript method. It's a matter of opinion though. This way people without JavaScript still get the helper text though.

Don't believe the rumor that there's an advantage using absolute positioning over display: none. True 10 years ago, but not today. Google is smart enough to figure out that they both serve the same purpose.